# Bitmap from StorageItemThumbnail shows wrong dimensions in GridView

Tags: c#, image, gridview, uwp

I am currently building an app and one bug that I can't seem to figure out is this:

[image: Gridview]

These images are PDF page snapshots, and are actually in portrait format. Somehow, it won't display correctly. I can actually see the wrong size and the size that it's supposed to show.

[image: Properties]

Does anyone have an idea why it would do this?

Converter code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    BitmapImage image = null;

    if (value != null)
    {
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(StorageItemThumbnail))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected a StorageItemThumbnail as binding input.");
        }

        if (targetType != typeof(ImageSource))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected ImageSource as binding output.");
        }

        if ((StorageItemThumbnail)value == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Thumbnail is null.");
            return image;
        }

        image = new BitmapImage();
        using (var thumbNailClonedStream = ((StorageItemThumbnail)value).CloneStream())
        {
            image.DecodePixelType = DecodePixelType.Logical;

            _ = image.SetSourceAsync(thumbNailClonedStream);
        }
    }

    return image;
}
```

Thumbnail retrieval (destinationFile = StorageFile):

```
StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await destinationFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 500, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);
CurrentPages.Add(new AppPage
{
    ImageFile = destinationFile,
    OriginalFile = file,
    Thumbnail = thumbnail
});
```

GridView XAML:

```
<GridView Name="pagesViewer" ItemsSource="{x:Bind CurrentPages, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,0,0,40" Grid.Row="1" CanDrag="True" CanDragItems="True" CanReorderItems="True" Background="White" AllowDrop="True" Drop="pagesViewer_Drop" DragOver="pagesViewer_DragOver">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:AppPage">
            <StackPanel Height="280" Width="200" Margin="12" AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind PageNumber}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Bind OriginalFile.Name}" Background="WhiteSmoke" IsRightTapEnabled="True">
                <StackPanel.ContextFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout.Items>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="DeletePage" Text="Remove Page" />
                            <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="AddBlankBefore" Text="Add Blank Before" />
                            <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="AddBlankAfter" Text="Add Blank After" />
                        </MenuFlyout.Items>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </StackPanel.ContextFlyout>
                <Image Source="{x:Bind Thumbnail, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ThumbnailConverter}}" Height="240" Width="200" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                <StackPanel Margin="0,12">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind PageNumber, Mode=OneWay}" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="15" TextAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsWrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="10" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bitmap from StorageItemThumbnail shows wrong dimensions in GridView

Please refer [`GetThumbnailAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getthumbnailasync?view=winrt-19041) document, The requested size, in pixels, of the longest edge of the thumbnail. Windows uses the `requestedSize` as a guide and tries to scale the thumbnail image **without reducing the quality** of the image. When you set `ThumbnailMode` as [`PicturesView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileproperties.thumbnailmode?view=winrt-19041#fields) and call GetThumbnailAsync method like the following

```
await destinationFile.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.PicturesView, 500, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);
```

It will cut image with 19 / 13, then the width will be limit as 500 and the height will be limit as 342.

For your scenario, we suggest you use `ThumbnailMode.SingleItem` to replace above and set Image Stretch property as `Fill`

```
StorageItemThumbnail thumbnail = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, 500, ThumbnailOptions.ResizeThumbnail);
```